# ArgumentError: comparison of NilClass with 1 failed min_by

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I need to find out the minimum of an array without nil.

```
[{val: 1},{val: nil}].min_by { |v| v[:val] }
```

gets

`ArgumentError: comparison of NilClass with 1 failed min_by`

My next approach was:

```
[{val: 1},{val: nil}].min_by { |v| v[:val] || 0 }
```

But this returns `{:duration=>nil}`

I only want to get the minimum value without the nil value - expected 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[{val: 1},{val: nil}].delete_if { |v| v[:val].nil? }.min_by { |v| v[:val] }
```

You can use [`delete_if`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if) to exclude array elements matching the block, in your case where the value is nil.

Answer (score 4):

You can also [reject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-reject) the nil value

```
[{val: 1},{val: nil}].reject { |v| v[:val].nil? }.min_by { |v| v[:val] }
```

Reject will return a new array, [delete_if](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if) will only delete the value from the matching block - both is possible. But I think [delete_if](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if) is more performant for your case.

Comment: Yes i'll need only an array without `nil` values. But also a good approach.